# RSA with custom engine openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption, evp-cipher, openssl-engine

I am looking to run this (URL)code with custom engine: https://sehermitage.web.fc2.com/program/src/rsa_evp.c

I want to implement below functions with engine.

```
EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, Engine e);
EVP_PKEY_CTX *EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(int id, ENGINE *e);
```

How do I register these function with custom engine? I didn't find any ENGINE_set_***  kind of functions to register respective function. Can anyone please guide me how to proceed with this.